# Проблема загрузки изображений на сервер

Tags: jquery, php, html5

Для загрузки на сервер (apache) используется решение [отсюда](http://habrahabr.ru/post/109079/). Серверная часть выглядит так:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
$SITEDIR = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 1024*9*1024)
{
echo ("Размер файла превышает три мегабайта");
exit;
}
// Проверяем загружен ли файл
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]))
{
// Если файл загружен успешно, перемещаем его
// из временной директории в конечную
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "{$SITEDIR}/uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
} else {
echo("Ошибка загрузки файла: ".$_FILES["file"]["error"]);
}
?>
```

После загрузки на сервер файлы изображений увеличиваются в размере раза в 1,5, и их формат не разпознется просмотрщиками.
При загрузке текстового файла с кодировкой utf-8 на сервере они сохраняются в виде крокозябр вида (utf-8 -> Windows-1252).
В чем зарыта собака?
Использовались различные способы чтения файлов (readAsDataURL, readAsBinaryString, readAsArrayBuffer), ни один не дал исходного файла на сервере.

Заголовки HTTP POST запроса:

```
self.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data, boundary="+boundary);
self.xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

var body = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
//var body;
body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='"+(params.fieldName || 'file')+"'; filename='" + params.file.name + "'\r\n";
body += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
//body += " Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n";
body += self.reader.result + "\r\n";
body += "--" + boundary + "--";
```

Comment: Всё можно решить гораздо проще. Используйте [FormData][1]. Вместе с jQuery [это может быть так][2].

   [1]:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData
   [2]:http://incode.pro/jquery/ajax-na-praktike-zagruzka-fajlov.html

Comment: Проблема решена перекодировкой содержимого файлов на сервере функцией base64_encode
...

// Если файл загружен успешно, перемещаем его
  // из временной директории в конечную
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "{$SITEDIR}/uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"])){
   file_put_contents( "{$SITEDIR}/uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"], base64_decode(file_get_contents("{$SITEDIR}/uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"])));

....

Answer (score 1):

*<sup>Вынесенный ответ из комментариев</sup>*

Проблема решена перекодировкой содержимого файлов на сервере функцией `base64_encode`:

```
// Если файл загружен успешно, перемещаем его 
// из временной директории в конечную 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "{$SITEDIR}/uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"])) { 
    file_put_contents("{$SITEDIR}/uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"], base64_decode(file_get_contents("{$SITEDIR}/uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"])))‌​;
```